# UIPickerView don't hide on didSelectRow

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

I'm new to Objective-C and iOS.

I need a UITextField as UIPickerView, this works fine, but when I select a item from the UIPickerView, it doesn't hide, I tried to set

```
[self.pickerLocales removeFromSuperview];
```

and

```
[self.pickerLocales setHidden=YES];
[self.pickerLocales.hidden=YES];
```

But that only hides the content of the UIPickerView, the "frame" of the UIPickerView remains visible.

Sorry, I tried to upload an image but I don't have enough reputation to upload an image.

In my .h file:

```
@interface UserPanelViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> {
        UIPickerView *pickerLocales;
    }
```

And in my .m file:

```
@synthesize pickerLocales;
In viewDidLoad:
pickerLocales.dataSource = self;
pickerLocales.delegate = self;
self.txtLocal.inputView = pickerLocales;
```

Comment: how do you add your pickerView to your View ?

Comment: edit your question and add to it

Comment: Thanks for reply to soon Kabira:
In my .h file:

interface UserPanelViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> {
    UIPickerView *pickerLocales;
}

synthesize pickerLocales;

And in my .m file:

In viewDidLoad:
pickerLocales = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
pickerLocales.dataSource = self;
pickerLocales.delegate = self;
self.txtLocal.inputView = pickerLocales;

Comment: you dont write Solved in the question yourself. Stackoverflow does some thing for us which everyone can easily understand (like showing how many answers a question has, downvotes,upvotes.). I will suggest you look at the faq to understand how stackoverflow works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can programmatically show keyboard for UITextField using this code:

```
[self.txtLocal becomeFirstResponder];
```

You can programmatically hide keyboard for UITextField using this code:

```
[self.txtLocal resignFirstResponder];
```

And in Your case instead of keyboard You use UIPickerView.

Invoke

```
[self.txtLocal resignFirstResponder];
```

in UIPickerView delegate method (– pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:
).

Comment: [self.txtLocal resignFirstResponder]; instead to self.txtLocal.inputView = pickerLocales; ?

Comment: Invoke this in UIPickerView delegate method - after choosing a value.

Comment: Sorry, I guess the delegate method in this case is didSelectRow right? I put your code there and work perfectly!

Thank you very much! I've tried to solve this for 2 days!

Comment: Great! I have updated the answer - check it if You like to know how to programmatically show keyboard ;)

Comment: Yeah, I know now how to show and hide keyboard programmatically, Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your UIPickerView is not an IBOutlet. Therefore you cannot have it connected to the actual picker object in the case that you used InterfaceBuilder/Storyboard Editor.

If you created it programmatically then please show how.

Double check whether your self.piclerLocales is nil or not, because you can send messages (call methods) of a nil object without any runtime error. Therefore you can call the setters but they would have no effect whatsoever.